# What was the first console or handheld to have a user interface outside of games?

Tags: gaming-history

Consoles like the NES didn't have any sort of menus when not playing a game. Nowadays, however, stuff like the Switch and PS4 have all sorts of stuff built in:

[image: The Nintendo Switch home menu]
 [image: The PS4 home menu]

**What was the first video game console or handheld to have a user interface without being in a game?**

Comment: Would something just to manage memory cards be enough of a "user interface" for you ?

Comment: *[Comments Cleaned up]* - This question has a [Meta discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13431/28182) about it's on-topicness: all interested parties, please weigh in there.

Comment: The Famicom Disk System had a screen that prompted you to put in a disk, but as far as I can tell, it didn't have any UI outside of that.

Comment: @Powerlord I’m thinking more like menus, which now do stuff like say what game’s in it and have settings, rather than just one prompt, which isn’t a menu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's pretty hazy by what you define as a user interface. Judging by the criteria you laid out in the comments then the [Sega Saturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sega_Saturn) (1994) is the first console to have a [home dashboard with various options](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VI7WS5CAbKA) including playing games, music, and console settings.

User Timmy Jim was correct, [stating](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352549/what-was-the-first-console-or-handheld-to-have-a-user-interface-outside-of-games/355324#comment495713_352549):

> Not sure if it's the first, but certainly a very early contender - the [Sega Saturn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpPHFIed7nE) from around the mid 90s had an interface that would load up if you didn't have a disc in I believe

User Fana also [pointed out](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/355362/228910):

> After some research, I've found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBADy67V80I) that shows a [Phillips CDi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philips_CD-i) interface (from 1992).
>
> It has a couple of options (like checking the memory cards, changing language / options, etc ...). I don't know if you would accept this as an "user interface".

Before this, the earliest main menu I could find was the [Sega CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sega_CD) (1991), but that shows only a [Press Start](https://www.flickr.com/photos/mitsurugi-w/8385062935/) which does not meet your criteria.

Earlier gaming devices were not consoles but actual computers such as the [Apple II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_II) (1977) and the [Commodore 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_64) (1982) but did accept inputs to start games. Neither of these are 'video game consoles' and thus do not fit your criteria.

A notable console is the [Atari 2600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_2600) (1977) for having the [first screensaver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/291399/was-the-atari-2600-the-first-home-console-to-have-a-screen-saver). While this could hardly be considered an interactive dashboard, it would turn on after a period of inactivity, change colors to prevent screen burn-in, and would turn off after user input. If we're playing loose with definitions, this is the first menu of any kind on a dedicated gaming console.

Answer (score 6):

After some research, I've found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBADy67V80I) that shows a CDi interface (from 1992).

It has a couple of options (like checking the memory cards, changing language / options, etc ...). I don't know if you would accept this as an "user interface".

Keep in mind that the CDi itself is a weird beast, mix between a video player and a gaming console. It has something like 5 models with different hardwares AND firmwares panning over 2-3 years.

Comment: Impressive find! I don't know if a CD player meets the qualifications of being a dedicated game console, but you certainly have my vote on this.

Comment: Upvoted, but I think the other counts more because it's explicitly a console. Good find, anyway!

Answer (score 2):

So in 1978, Video brain. had a game list you can select from games that are already there. It's kinda cool. [image: The first home screen]